# Como corrigir erro Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou tentando implementar um mecanismo de pesquisa no meu componente, mas está causando um loop. Pego o storeData do meu contexto e tento filtrar os dados para poder pesquisar. Como posso resolver esse problema de loop?

Componente Search:

```
 import { Container } from "./styles"
import { useState, useMemo } from "react"
import { useStores } from "../../hooks/useStores"

export const Search = () => {
    const { storeData } = useStores()
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')


    storeData.filter((store) => {
        const storeName = store.name.toLowerCase()
        const searchText = setSearch(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
        return storeName.includes(searchText)
    })


    return (
        <Container>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={search}
                placeholder="Pesquisa"
                onChange={event => setSearch(event.target.value)}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="15.000,00"
            />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Componente useStores:

```
 import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'
import apiMock from './data.json'

export const StoresContext = createContext([]);

export const StoresProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState(apiMock.stores)

  return (
    <StoresContext.Provider value={{ storeData }}>
      {children}
    </StoresContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useStores = () => {
  return useContext(StoresContext)
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 storeData.filter((store) => {
        const storeName = store.name.toLowerCase()
        const searchText = setSearch(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
        return storeName.includes(searchText)
    })
```

O pedaço de código acima tem que ser executado apenas quando necessário, indo pra uma função, dentro do `useEffect` ou dentro de um `if` por exemplo, porque dentro desse filter, vc tá alterando o state do componente(com o `setSearch`) e isso gera um re-render do componente, que vai novamente executar o trecho de código acima, assim infinitamente

Answer (score -1):

Como disse o nosso amigo @placementw, o seu filter está usando o setSearch, que altera o state desse componente, logo ele é renderizado de novo, e executa esse filter de novo...

Você precisa quebrar esse cíclo de alguma forma.

Tem que remover esse setSearch daí. Se você tirar o setSearch do método filter e colocar o .tolowercase() no value lá embaixo, acredito que já traria o efeito desejado...

```
     import { Container } from "./styles"
import { useState, useMemo } from "react"
import { useStores } from "../../hooks/useStores"

export const Search = () => {
    const { storeData } = useStores()
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')


    storeData.filter((store) => {
        const storeName = store.name.toLowerCase()
       
        return storeName.includes(searchText)
    })


    return (
        <Container>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={search.toLowerCase()}
                placeholder="Pesquisa"
                onChange={event => setSearch(event.target.value)}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="15.000,00"
            />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: Boa essa plataforma, cara dá -1 e nem comentário coloca.

Answer (score -3):

Eu já tive isso quando tentei usar functions normais em alguns casos, mas só era trocar pra arow function que funcionava. Tenta colocar os parenteses ali no seu onchange no event pra ele saber que aquilo é um parâmetro de uma arow function, pode ser que seja isso.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nem é isso, o OnChange está certo.